# Php/Slim valid MySQL query prepared statements work separately but fail when used together

Tags: php, mysql, slim

I'm developing a RESTApi using Php with Slim framework to connect an Android App to a MySQL db (Sending test requests with Postman right now). The app is a song request app for a live music event in my town- Every artist who participates in the show adds their songs to the app, and attendees at the show can select and request a song which sends an email to the artist with their position in the queue.

I'm trying to insert into a table called setqueues(ShowID int, SongID int, ArtistID int, Position int), but first I have to see if the ShowID given has any songs assigned to it. If it does I take the number of rows returned, add 1, and assign it to a variable called $pos; otherwise $pos = 1. I then try to insert a new row into the table, but am getting

> Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean

whenever I try to do this. My code is:

index.php

```
$app->post('/songtoqueue', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    if(!haveEmptyParameters(array('show_id', 'song_id', 'artist_id'), $request, $response)){
        $request_data = $request->getParsedBody();
        $show_id = $request_data['show_id'];
        $song_id = $request_data['song_id'];
        $artist_id = $request_data['artist_id'];
        $db = new DbOperations;
        $result = $db->addSongToShow($show_id, $song_id, $artist_id);

        if($result == SHOW_SONG_ADDED){
            $message = array();
            $message['error'] = false;
            $message['message'] = 'Song added to Show successfully';
            $response->write(json_encode($message));
            return $response
                        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                        ->withStatus(201);
        }else if($result == SHOW_SONG_FAILURE){
            $message = array();
            $message['error'] = true;
            $message['message'] = 'Some error occurred while attempting to add Song to Show.';
            $response->write(json_encode($message));
            return $response
                        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
                        ->withStatus(422);
        }
    }
    return $response
        ->withHeader('Content-type', 'application/json')
        ->withStatus(422);
});
```

DbOperations.php

```
  public function addSongToShow($show_id, $song_id, $artist_id){
      $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (SELECT * FROM setqueues WHERE ShowID = ?) as c");
      $stmt->bind_param("i", $show_id);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($count);
      $stmt->fetch();
      $pos = 0;
      if($count == 0){
        $pos = 1;
      }else{
        $pos = $count + 1;
      }
      $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO setqueues(ShowID, SongID, ArtistID, Position) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");
      $stmt->bind_param("iiii", $show_id, $song_id, $artist_id, $pos);
      if($stmt->execute()){
        return SHOW_SONG_ADDED;
      }
      return SHOW_SONG_FAILURE;

  }
```

DbConnect.php

```
<?php

  class DbConnect{
    private $con;

    function connect(){
      include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Constants.php';

      $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

      if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect" . mysqli_connect_error();
        return null;
      }

      return $this->con;
    }
  }
```

I have checked that the queries run properly in phpmyadmin, and can get them to work if I only use one or the other, but any time I attempt to do both my code fails and I get the error above, with the offending line being

> $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO setqueues(ShowID, SongID, ArtistID, Position) VALUES (?,?,?,?)");

There are already many questions on here where the solution was incorrect MySQL statements; however, I am certain these queries are correct, and have even tried copy/pasting the auto generated insert statement from phpmyadmin into my code. The issue is using both of the above queries together. Any advice is greatly appreciated

--UPDATE--
This was solved by enabling mysqli error reporting with the line

> mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

before my connect statement. This allowed me to see that I needed to add $stmt->close(); in between my queries, because mysqli uses unbuffered queries by default

Comment: Binding to boolean is not supported by the database driver. Map the boolean value to an integer (true => 1, false => 0) instead.